# Background image to background colour transition/animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently having an issue with adding a hover CSS3 or a jQuery transition to a div with a background image on it. I want the background image to fade into a background color on hover.

very basic example of a simple background image to background color hover

```
.div1 {
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-10.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
}

.div1:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Now this works how you would expect but how could i make the background image fade into the background color?

I tried to add a simple CSS3 transition to the hover but this doesn't work as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9JXG/) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant animate/transition a background image into a color, but you can fake the effect by applying the image to a psuedo element overlayed on your div, and animating its opacity out on hover. The benefit being it will animate both *in* and *out*.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9JXG/1/)

You can do this with the following CSS:

```
.div1 {    
    height:200px;
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
}
.div1:after{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:'';
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-10.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    opacity:1;
    transition: 3s;
}

.div1:hover:after {
    opacity:0;    
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with text over the image aswell? Text seems to interfere with it?

Answer (score 3):

Add an inner div that changes the background like this:

```
.inner {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.div1:hover .inner {
    background:red;
    transition: 3s;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv3L7/)

Comment: Is it possible to do a fade out with this once you un hover a certain item?

Answer (score 0):

Smooth example with **css keyframe animation** without hover

example [**Keyframe animation Background red fade**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/L9JXG/3/)

> html

```
 <div class="div1">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

> css

```
.div1 {
        background:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-10.jpg");
        background-size:cover;
        height:200px;
        width:600px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .overlay {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:rgba(255, 10, 10, 0);
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        /* Standard syntax */
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-play-state: running;
        animation-direction: alternate;
    }
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        0% {
            background:rgba(255, 10, 10, 0);
        }
        100% {
            background:rgba(255, 10, 10, 1);
        }
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
     @keyframes fade {
        0% {
            background:rgba(255, 10, 10, 0);
        }
        100% {
            background:rgba(255, 10, 10, 1);
        }
    }
    }
```